# Can't access uploaded image to generate thumbnail in PHP

Tags: permissions, php, upload

I had trouble fixing the file uploading, but then I ran `chmod a+w /var/www` and it worked - files were being uploaded to my specified directory.

However, my script also generates a thumbnail immediately after the file is uploaded. This part is not working. I'm assuming that the files uploaded by the script are locked (they have a small lock appearing near them when going to the directory manually) and it can't grab the uploaded file and create a new thumbnail file based on it.

I'm not getting any error or something.

How do I edit the permissions in the way that lets me create new files using "locked" files?

Comment: Please, please _please_ do not make `/var/www` world writeable!

Comment: Modify your script to set permissions after generating a thumb nail. In addition, rather then making /var/www world rw, use an upload dorectory, such as /var/www/images . Use the lowest lever of permissions possible. I keep files owned by root with ro access and allow www-data rwx access only on critical files. I lock down php as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to work out your permissions correctly. If this is a web application than the user doing the file manipulation is probably `www-data`. So all files and directories need to be owned by the `www-data` group and user. And `www-data` should have full permissions for those files and directories.

1. Give `www-data` ownership of all files and dirs in DocumentRoot: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`.
2. Change permission so www-data has `rwx` priveleges: `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www`.
3. Add yourself to the `www-data` group  so you can make changes as well: `sudo adduser <username> www-data`. Logout and back in.
4. Read up on unix privileges and maybe tweak the permission within `/var/www` to be a bit tighter.